# Export SonarQube report in pdf format

Tags: sonarqube

I wanted to export the sonarqube report in pdf/excel format. Below are the things already tried:

1. Tried using Governance plugins but it throws error saying:

`What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':sonarqube'.
 No license for governance`

2. Open excel-> Click Data menu-> From Web-> in Address added localhost:9000-> selected project and tables to import. It keeps in downloading state for ever and never gets downloaded.

If anyone has done export in anyformat which I can send over mail then please help me with their inputs.

Comment: Can you specify what version of SonarQube you are using? There are a few .CSV plugins to do this but they depend on sonarQube version. Here is one for example. https://docs.codescan.io/hc/en-us/articles/360012009891-Exporting-your-issues-as-a-CSV-file